# Excel OleDb C# - Cannot select range if worksheet has special characters

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, oledbcommand

I have run into a snag when reading info from a workbook in excel that contains a "#" in the name of the sheet. I am able to select the WHOLE worksheet but not a range in the worksheet.

Code:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string Import_FileName = "C:/TestExcel/TestWorkbook.xlsm";
            conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Import_FileName + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'";
            using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                comm.CommandText = "Select * from [Sheet #1$A1:A22]";

                comm.Connection = conn;

                using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                {
                    da.SelectCommand = comm;
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }

            }
        }
```

And the following queries work just fine.

```
comm.CommandText = "Select * from [Sheet #1$]";
comm.CommandText = "Select * from [Sheet2$A1:A22]";
```

I get the following exception saying it cannot find the table in question.

```
The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet .1$A1:A22'.
```